# tsconfig paths - resolve @dashboard to ./components/dashboard/index

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have the following folder structure

```
./components/dashboard/index.tsx
./components/dashboard/users/usertable.tsx
```

I would like to have a tsconfig where I can do:

```
import dashboard from '@dashboard'
import usertable from '@dashboard/users/usertable
```

I can get the first behaviour by setting

```
"paths": {
      "@dashboard":["./components/dashboard"],
    }
```

and the second one by setting

```
"paths": {
      "@dashboard/*":["./components/dashboard/*"],
    }
```

How can I get them both at the same time though?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite simple - setting both paths at the same time:

```
"paths": {
      "@dashboard":["./components/dashboard"],
      "@dashboard/*":["./components/dashboard/*"]
    }
```